# OSquery can't load extension

Tags: c++, boost, monitoring, osquery

I have created an osquery extension using C++ and OSquery SDK 3.3.0

On Windows, from command line all runs perfect. osqueryd.exe loads my extension and all works fine. In task manager I can see osqueryd.exe and my extensión running.
When I try to run oswueryd as a service, using service manager, my extensión is not loaded. I can see osqueryd.exe running but my extension is not running.
With procmon.exe I can see that osqueryd try to load my extension.

extensions.load contains the full path to my extension.

osquery.flags contains:

```
--disable_extensions=false
--config_path=C:\ProgramData\osquery\osquery.conf
--extensions_autoload=C:\ProgramData\osquery\extensions.load
```

extensions.load content:

```
C:\ProgramData\osquery\extensions\myextension.exe
```

Permissions to extension folder is configured Ok.

UPDATE

From command line, as an administrator, if I run

```
.\osqueryd.exe --verbose
```

No errors appears.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the contents of `extensions.load`? Can you share?
Also, if you add `--verbose` as a flag and run with `./osqueryd.exe --flagfile osquery.flags` in a shell (not via service) what is in the logs?

Comment: Updated with extensions.load contents. Yes, I run as a service with this parameter. By default, osquery register the service with this parameter

Comment: @groob I have updated my post with your questions. Thx

Comment: Consider that your extension can be run separately to debug this situation.  Remove the --extensions_autoload option from your Osqueryd and restart the service.  Then in an Admin CMD window, run your extension .exe.  Watch the osquery logs to see when it connects. If that works, then create a separate service for your extension and run that.   My guess is that your are probably doing something that doesn't work when your extension runs as a service... for example, are you doing printf to stdout?

Comment: @AlexM I have run osqueryd as a service and my extensión from consoles with admin rights and --verbose parameter. My extensión show an error "Extension socket not available: \\.\pipe\osquery.em". This error is emited in my extension from startExtension function